# android : how to run thread in Asynch till get response from AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In my program through AsynchTask collecting data from server and wait for user choice from the data via spinner(AlertDialog.Builder is used to display data in spinner format).

My code is :

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 1500;
    protected long startTime = 0;   


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new InitialSetAsync().execute();

    }

    private class InitialSetAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            InitialSetting ins = new InitialSetting(Splash.this);
            ins.doInitialSetting();

            try {
                while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < _splashTime) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Splash.this.finish();

        }

    }

}
```

Data displaying portion as in spinner format:

```
public class InitialSetting {

    private Context context;

    DbTransaction dbTran;
    Process checkProcess;
    String userCountry;
    String country = "";
    String[] availableCountries;
    int flag=0;
    public InitialSetting(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int doInitialSetting() {
            checkProcess = new Process();
        String hasVisit = checkProcess.retrieveFromPreference(context);
        if (hasVisit.equals("true")) {

        } else {
availableCountries = checkProcess.checkAvailableCountries();

            final AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ab.setSingleChoiceItems(availableCountries, -1,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {



                                    country = availableCountries[whichButton];

                                    if (!country.equals("") && country != null) {

                                        Configuration.setCounty(country);

                                        checkProcess.copyDatabaseFromServer(
                                                country, context);
                                        dbTran.storePreference(country);

                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                    ab.show();

                }
            });

        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

In my case, the thread is running before the user select the value from Spinner and cause error. How to pause Asynch task till the user select the values.

Comment: You are trying to misuse Async Task...What do you really want...Data for the spinner is coming from the Async and upon selection of item in spinner you call another service right...is this something you want..?

Comment: @Pragnani , i want to load some set of data from server on basis of user choice when app loads. If i avoid Asynch Task, the server synchronization didnot work when i deploy apk in real device.